How computationally advantageous are e-bits compared to probabilistically dependent classic bits
Let a "classical entangled bit" be defined as 2 classical bits put in a dependent probabilistic state like $\left| E\right> = \frac{1}{2} \left|00\right> + \frac{1}{2} \left|11\right>$. Now, how to quantitatively prove that this is not as computationally strong as a quantum entangled bit put in the state $\left| \psi\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|00\right> + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left|11\right>$ for example. I have tried to prove for example that it can't solve the CHSH game with a probability higher than $75\%$ (unlike an e-bit which can solve it with more than $85\%$ chance) but I wasn't successful.
Can someone help me with this? and if it is a known topic could someone direct me to some helpful resources to learn more about it?

Consider the CHSH game.
Alice and Bob share a pair of entangled qubits in the form:
$$| \psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | 0_A\rangle \otimes |0_B\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} | 1_A\rangle \otimes | 1_B\rangle, $$
where the subscript $A$ corresponds to Alice's qubit, and subscript $B$ for Bob's qubit.
A referee then sends a classical bit to each Alice and Bob, who have previously come up with the following strategy:

If Alice receives $0$, she leaves her qubit alone and measures it.
If Alice receives $1$, she rotates her qubit by $\pi/4$ and measures it.
If Bob receives $0$, he rotates his qubit by $\pi/8$ and measures it.
If Bob receives $1$, he rotates his qubit by $-\pi/8$ and measures it.

Since CHSH is super annoying to analyze, I will only consider the case where Alice receives a $1$ and Bob receives a $0$ from the referee. This should be enough to show the difference between entangled and classical-correlated states, but you perform this analysis for the remaining three conditions.
So, in this particular case, before measurement, the shared state is given by:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
| \psi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} RY(\pi/2)| 0_A\rangle \otimes RY(\pi/4)|0_B\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} RY(\pi/2) RY(\pi/2)| 1_A\rangle \otimes RY(\pi/4)| 1_B\rangle
\\
\\
| \psi\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|0_A\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|1_A\rangle \right) \otimes \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|0_B\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|1_B\rangle \right) 
\\
&+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|0_A\rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|1_A\rangle \right) \otimes \left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|0_B\rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|1_B\rangle \right)
\\
\\
| \psi\rangle &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right)| 0_A 0_B\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) - \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right)| 0_A 1_B\rangle 
\\
&+ \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) - \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right)| 1_A 0_B\rangle 
+ \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right) | 1_A 1_B\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
Alice and Bob win when they measure equal values. So the probability of winning is the probability of measuring state $| 0_A 0_B\rangle$ plus the probability of measuring state $| 1_A 1_B\rangle$:
$$P_{\text{win}} = 2 \left |\frac{1}{2} \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right) \right |^2 \approx 0.853$$
Now, for the case of a classical correlated state (which you call $E$) with equal probability of having state $|00\rangle$ or state $|11\rangle$, it is not as if you had the "sum" of the two states. You either have one or the other. So you can perform the same analysis just using the two separate states:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|E_1\rangle &= RY(\pi/2)| 0_A\rangle \otimes RY(\pi/4)|0_B\rangle
\\
\\
|E_1\rangle &= \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|0_A\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|1_A\rangle \right) \otimes \left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|0_B\rangle + \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|1_B\rangle \right) 
\\
\\
|E_1\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 0_A 0_B\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 0_A 1_B\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 1_A 0_B\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 1_A 1_B\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
$$ \textbf{or} $$
$$
\begin{aligned}
|E_2\rangle &= RY(\pi/2)| 1_A\rangle \otimes RY(\pi/4)| 1_B\rangle
\\
\\
|E_2\rangle &= \left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|0_A\rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4} \right)|1_A\rangle \right) \otimes \left(-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|0_B\rangle + \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right)|1_B\rangle \right)
\\
\\
|E_2\rangle &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 0_A 0_B\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 0_A 1_B\rangle - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 1_A 0_B\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) | 1_A 1_B\rangle
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, since Alice and Bob are sharing either $|E_2\rangle$ or $|E_1\rangle$, each with probability $1/2$, the probability of winning is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{\text{win}} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(P_{00}+P_{11}\right)|_{E=E1} + \frac{1}{2} \left(P_{00}+P_{11}\right)|_{E=E2}
\\
\\
P_{\text{win}} &= \frac{1}{2} \left(\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right|^2 + \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right|^2 \right) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right|^2 + \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{8} \right) \right|^2 \right)
\\
\\
P_{\text{win}} &= \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}
\\
\\
P_{\text{win}} &= 0.5
\end{aligned}
$$
So, as you can see, the probability of winning without an entangled state is significantly lower for this particular case, which lowers to overall probability of winning the game.
One could argue that, for the specific case we are analyzing (Alice receives $0$, Bob receives $1$) the presented strategy is not optimal. However, if we try to optimize it, then the probability of winning in the other scenarios decreases (you can work out the maths in a similar way as above to prove this is the case).

Thanks, this is helpful, but what I wanted to prove is more general than that: I wanted to show that no matter what strategy alice and bob choose (not necessarily the one we used with e-bits ), they won't achieve higher than $75%$ probability

The proof that any classical strategy cannot achieve higher than 75% could be extended to strategies using |E> states, because they are still just classical mixtures

Yes, this correct.
